# Wordpress WP-CLI search-replace syntax for URLs

Tags: wordpress, bash, wp-cli

I want to change this sentence:

```
<iframe width="850" height="478" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4zH9Zca1vRM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To this:

```
https://www.youtu.be/4zH9Zca1vRM
```

I can do it for every iframe of youtube video in the database. What is the right sentence for do it? I gess something like this:

**step 1**. Replacing first part:

```
wp search-replace '<iframe width="*" height="*" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' 'https://www.youtu.be/'  --regex
```

**step 2**. Replacing last part:

```
wp search-replace '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' ''  --regex
```

Is it right? I'm not sure about quotes and wildcards.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update with regular expressions, be sure to escape all the forward slashes for the first argument:

```
$ wp search-replace '<iframe width="([0-9]+)" height="([0-9]+)" src="https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen><\/iframe>' 'https://www.youtu.be/\3' --regex
```

Disregard the first two matched, since they're not important and use third match in the second (replacement) argument.

Also remember to:

```
$ wp cache flush
```

It's a good idea to do a --dry-run first to see if there are any tables affected that you might not intend to modify.

http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/

Answer (score 0):

You won't need regex for this, you can quote it with a single tick. You can run this to test and show the replacements that would occur. Remove the --dry-run flag to make the actual replacements.

```
$ wp search-replace '<iframe width="850" height="478" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4zH9Zca1vRM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' 'https://www.youtu.be/4zH9Zca1vRM' --dry-run
```

Comment: Yes, it works for this case, but does not work with wildcards: width="[wildcard here]" height="[wildcard here]" thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yet an other regex,
this one fixes youtube links or iframe http or https

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVoUPnXqvNE&whatever#t=30
- http://www.youtube.com/embed/gVoUPnXqvNE?feature=whatever#t=30

and remplaces it by a simple string that will display as embed in wordpress:

https://youtu.be/gVoUPnXqvNE

```sh
$ wp search-replace '<(?:a|iframe)\s[^>]*(?:href|src)="https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(?:(?:\?&)[^"#\s]*)?(#t=[0-9]+)?"[^>]*>.*?<\/(?:a|iframe)>' 'https://youtu.be/\1\2' --regex --regex-flags='s'
```